# When you're looking at your google activity and it says viewed next to it, does that mean you actually viewed that topic in your cards?

Tags: google-account, google

When you're looking at your google activity in your iPhone. Next to some of my cards it says viewed but I didn't actually view that topic. So what does that mean?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Since the question mentioned "iPhone", this doesn't look like a question about Android, and thus it's migrated to our sister site for Apple products, [apple.se].